# Got JS error all the time 'fadeOutAndRemove'

Tags: support, questions, comments

After updated the top menu bar, I always can't leave comment and get this JS error.

I am using Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m. But there is no error when I am using incognito mode.

[image]

PS: tried to clear all related cache, cookie.

Comment: No repro on 31.0.1650.63 m

Comment: Do you have any userscripts installed?

Comment: @Antony is most likely correct, *something* is taking over the `$` sign of jQuery and cause the Stack Exchange plugins to not be recognized.

Comment: I disabled all chrome extensions, but the problem still here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something loading jQuery on it's own, nuking our copy with methods added.  You'll need to fix or remove whatever user script or other content your browser is injecting that interferes with the page.

Unless this user script is scoped to just our sites (in that case, stop including jQuery - we already do that) you'll likely get problems like this on any major website using jQuery.

Comment: I disable all extension and quit all Chrome windows & background jobs, now everything work perfectly.

Comment: "Stop including jQuery" - blasphemy!

Comment: @mikeTheLiar BYOjQ